# How to setup AutoFixture.AutoMoq to moq all contructor parameters?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture to mock an external library that doesn't always implement interfaces, but has a default ctor without parameters.

Currently, I am using Moq/AutoMoq framework like that:

```
mocker.GetMock<HeavyDependency>()
      .Setup(x => x.GetData())
      .Returns("TEST DATA");
```

I want to have the same behaviour with AutoFixture.AutoMoq. My code:

```
namespace AutoFixtureNUnit.TestsCs
{
    public class HeavyDependency1
    {
        public HeavyDependency1() => Debug.WriteLine("HeavyDependency1");
    }
    public class HeavyDependency2
    {
        public HeavyDependency2() => Debug.WriteLine("HeavyDependency2");
    }

    public class MyClassWithHeavyDependency
    {
        private readonly HeavyDependency1 dep1;
        private readonly HeavyDependency2 dep2;

        public MyClassWithHeavyDependency() => Debug.WriteLine("MyClassWithHeavyDependency default.");
        public MyClassWithHeavyDependency(HeavyDependency1 h1, HeavyDependency2 h2)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyClassWithHeavyDependency injected.");
            dep1 = h1;
            dep2 = h2;
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        private Fixture _fixture;
        private Mock<HeavyDependency1> _heavyMock;
        MyClassWithHeavyDependency _sut;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _fixture = new Fixture();

            _fixture
                .Customize(new ConstructorCustomization(typeof(MyClassWithHeavyDependency), new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
                .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization(){ConfigureMembers = false});

            _heavyMock = new Mock<HeavyDependency1>();
            _fixture.Inject(_heavyMock.Object);

            _sut = _fixture.Create<MyClassWithHeavyDependency>();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Assert.Pass("Your first passing test");
        }
    }
}
```

`MyClassWithHeavyDependency` has a ctor that takes dependent objects and code above calls that ctor.

So far so good. I am injecting the Mock of the dependent object and verifying calls.

**The problem:**

For the mocks that are Injected, the constructor is called with the Mock like: `{Mock<AutoFixtureNUnit.TestsCs.HeavyDependency1:00000001>.Object}`.

However, for all other types it is called with the parameter of `{AutoFixtureNUnit.TestsCs.HeavyDependency2}`. Which is not what I want and is not used by the current tests. Not a Moq object, right?

It is mocking my own interfaces as well.

**Question:**

Can I somehow specify that AutoFixture.AutoMoq should mock all ctor parameters that are not manually mocked by me?

Because Freezing/injecting every single one is not different from manual mock setup and requires a lot of code changes every time I add ctor parameter.

Actually, I can see `HeavyDependency1` ctor called as well. Seems strange.

Comment: Could you please update the description with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the full scenario that fails? It's hard to understand what exactly you would like to achieve :-/

Comment: The purpose of *AutoFixture.AutoMoq* is to act as an [Auto-Mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container), so it ought to already fill in all dependencies with Moq-generated Test Doubles. Thus, I'm not sure I understand the nature of the problem. Can you please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Updated question with sample.

Comment: The problem is that `dep1` and `dep2` are [Concrete Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/08/31/ConcreteDependencies), and by design, *AutoMoq* [doesn't mock those](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/25/ChangingthebehaviorofAutoFixtureauto-mockingwithMoq).